# show loading-gif immediately

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on wordpress cms. I have page-template which holds the selected posts ( it works through a plugin). Now there is a remove-post button along with every selected post. If someone would click the remove-post button I wanted to show a loading-gif so that the person knows removal-process is going on (naturally not everyone is tech savvy). So I searched for a solution and employed this bit of javascript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      jQuery('#page-load')
        .hide()  // hide it initially
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            jQuery(this).show("fast");
        })
        .ajaxStop(function() {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

along with this bit of HTML. Together it kind of did the job.

```
<div id="page-load"><img src="http://awesomesite.com/images/loader.gif" /></div>
```

**ISSUE**: Problem is, on clicking the remove-post link the loading gif shows very very late, almost when the page is reloaded. What I wish to get done is that the loading gif should immediately appear on clicking the remove-post button and then hide once reload is complete (once the clicked post is removed).

> I do not have an ajax code, I am just using a wp-plugin. Somehow this
>   worked so the snippet is there. I might be doing it
>   completely wrong. So it would be great if you can suggest a solution

If you find it relevant here is a part of the plugin which generates the remove link.

```
function wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id) {
    if (wpfp_is_user_can_edit()) {
        $wpfp_options = wpfp_get_options();
        $class = 'wpfp-link remove-parent';
        $link = "<a id='rem_$post_id' class='$class' href='?wpfpaction=remove&amp;page=1&amp;postid=". $post_id ."' title='".wpfp_get_option('rem')."' rel='nofollow'>".wpfp_get_option('rem')."</a>";
        $link = apply_filters( 'wpfp_remove_favorite_link', $link );
        echo $link;
    }
}
```

**BOTTOMLINE**: I am using this solution on a better than nothing basis. I found these snippets somewhere on SO only. As I said earlier, my approach might be completely wrong. End of the day what I need is that **when someone clicks the remove link the page should immediately show a loading gif and then hide when the reload is complete**. Please help me out with a better solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `ajax code`?

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.`

Comment: @RohanKumar I do not have an ajax code, I am just using a wp-plugin. Somehow this worked so the snippet is there. I have a feeling that I am doing it completely wrong. Could you point me to a right resource please or suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wp-plugin uses Ajax :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var $pageLoad = jQuery('#page-load');
        $pageLoad.hide();
        jQuery(this).ajaxStart(function() {
            $pageLoad.show("fast");
        })
        .ajaxStop(function() {
            $pageLoad.hide();
        });
    }); 
 </script>
```

In fact, a faster way to make the loading image appears would be to set a 'click' event on the button you're clicking on to show the loading image... but that means you must show us the HTML.

EDIT : Now that we have more code, you can use the following script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var $pageLoad = jQuery('#page-load');
        $pageLoad.hide();
        jQuery('.remove-parent').on('click', function() {
            $pageLoad.show("fast");
        });
        jQuery(this).ajaxStop(function() {
            $pageLoad.hide();
        });
    }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried ur code and it works as it used to, not immediately though. I have updated the question with the function which generates the link. Does it help to better figure out things?

Comment: Thank you, i've edited my answer. Edit: sorry there was a mistake, it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store the 'loading' image locally

CSS

```
#page-load { display: none; background: url(/local/path/to/assets/loading.gif) no-repeat}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#page-load" ).show();
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( "#page-load" ).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to utilise the onClick event of the 'remove-post' button? You code is essentially trapping *any* ajax request and displaying the gif.

HTML:

```
<button class="remove-post">Remove Post</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $pageload = $('#page-load');
    $pageload.hide();  // hide it initially
    $('.remove-post').on('click', function(e) {
        $pageload.show('fast');
    });
});
```

As part of your ajax result handler you can hide the gif again

```
$.ajax(
    ...
    success: function() 
        $('#page-load').hide();
    });
```